# Integrating exception handling in Python 'with'

Tags: python, exception

A simple way to open a file and read its contents is using [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open ('file.txt', "r") as filehandle:
    contents = filehandle.read()
```

But that does not include excepting file opening errors in a way that a `try/except` would:

```
try:
    filehandle = open('file.txt', 'r')
    contents = filehandle.read()
except IOError:
    print('There was an error opening the file!')
    sys.exit()
```

Is there a way to integrate a failure message in the with statement so that it exits gracefully if the opening fails that would be done in fewer lines of code than the second example yet provide the same functionality?  If not that, is there anything more elegant (or minimalist) than the second form?

Answer (score 0):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def safe_open(fname,mode):
    try:
        fh = open(fname,mode)
    except IOError:
        print "ERROR OPENING FILE :",fname
        sys.exit()
    else:
        yield fh
        try:
            fh.close()
        except:
            pass


with safe_open("nofile","rb") as f:
    f.write("blah")
```

Im not sure that its more elegant but meh ...

Comment: this does not look very elegant

Comment: thats only because you see the implementation ... if you just do `from util import safe_open` ... then use it. then its pretty elegant ... (